# Is $0x1a a register here?

Tags: x86, disassembly

```
Dump of assembler code for function read@plt:
0x0000000000402458 <read@plt+0>:    jmpq   *0x2b4f72(%rip)        # 0x6b73d0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+232>
0x000000000040245e <read@plt+6>:    pushq  $0x1a
0x0000000000402463 <read@plt+11>:   jmpq   0x4022a8
```

Anyone knows?

BTW,how does `read` knows he comes to the end of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a immediate value. `pushq` pushes a value onto the stack, which *may* be a register, but you'll find they're denoted by operands like `%rbx`.

The `$0x1a` is an immediate value - you can tell this also by the length of that instruction (five bytes, from `x+6` to `x+10`). The `pushq` instruction is capable of pushing a register, a memory content (64 bits) or a 32-bit immediate value (sign extended to 64 bits).

In this case, the five bytes are the opcode `0x68` along with the 32-bit value to push. If you were to examine the memory, it would probably look like `0x68 0x1a 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

And don't be fooled by that code, it's not the "real" `read` call at all. It's a stub used to fix up references at runtime where code sections may be shared amongst processors, even at different base addresses.

The PLT is a small-footprint per-process stub which jumps to the real shared code the first time, fixing itself up in the process, so as to jump directly there in future. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469274/what-does-plt-mean-here/5469334#5469334) for an explanation of this process.

Comment: So  `$0x1a` is indeed a register, `%rbx` to be specific?

Comment: No, `$0x1a` is not a register, it's an immediate value of hexadecimal `1a` (decimal 26) the end-of-file indicator for Windows and its predecessors.

Comment: So I can imagine there're other similar calls whether finally goes to the same syscall,but with a different parameter as `$0x1a`?

Comment: Don't mistake the `read` _function_ as a syscall. A syscall is the interface to the _kernel_ using either int80 or the newer sysenter (or perhaps another method depending on architecture). `read()` is simply another userland thing to kernel programmers (`sys_read` is the syscall it eventually gets to). As to other calls, they would have their own place in the PLT.

Comment: Isn't EOF defined as `-1` in stdio.h?

Comment: @cpuer, that's a C thing. `read` is not a C thing, it operates at a different level of abstraction. The UNIX `read` call will return the number of bytes read, or zero on end of file. -1 represents an error.

Comment: `The $0x1a is an immediate value - you can tell this also by the length of that instruction (five bytes, from x+6 to x+10).` I don't see how can I tell `$0x1a` is immediate from the length of the instruction:(

Comment: @cpuer, an instruction to push a register would be very short because (1) it would be done a lot; and (2) you don't need many bits to specify one of the registers (there are only 16 64-bit registers so you only need 4 bits to specify which one).

Comment: @paxdiablo,can you explain how are variables in shared libraries referenced by loader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306908/how-are-variables-in-shared-libraries-referenced-by-loader

Answer (score 0):

Registers do not (ordinarily) have a memory location, they are a CPU register.

Comment: When we say register,we never mean anything other than CPU register,right?

Comment: No, a "register" can mean other things depending on context, but if the context is low level assembly, then yes, it is almost always a CPU register.

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned yet, but the leading $ sign denotes a constant.  Simple as that when looking at assembly dumps.

One easy pitfall:  when looking a dumps of unlinked binaries, don't be fooled by 0x00000000 all over the place.  Without the leading $, those are linker relocations, not constant 0 values.