# How are variables in shared libraries referenced by loader?

Tags: shared-libraries, elf

I now understand how dynamic functions are referenced, by procedure linkage table like below:

```
Dump of assembler code for function foo@plt:
0x0000000000400528 <foo@plt+0>: jmpq   *0x2004d2(%rip)        # 0x600a00 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+40>
0x000000000040052e <foo@plt+6>: pushq  $0x2
0x0000000000400533 <foo@plt+11>:    jmpq   0x4004f8
(gdb) disas 0x4004f8
No function contains specified address.
```

But I don't know how dynamic variables are referenced,though I found the values are populated in the GOT once started,but there's no stub like above,how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic loader relocates all references to variables before transferring control to the user program.

There is no "stub" for them, because once the user program starts executing, it is not possible for the loader to regain control and update variable addresses. If this isn't clear to you, then you have not *really* understood how the PLT lazy-resolution stub works.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are accessed indirectly, via a global offset table.

- When compiling a program, the compiler generates code that performs
  indirect accesses, and emits relocation information specifying the
  entry in the global offset table being used.
- The linker performs these relocations when creating the final
  dynamically loadable object, resulting in machine code that does not
  need further patching at load time.

To see this in action, consider the following code fragment.

```
int v1;
int f(void) { return !v1; }
```

The function `f` references a global `v1`. The machine code generated
for the function looks like the following (on an i386):

```
% gcc -c -fpic a.c
% objdump --disassemble --reloc a.o
[snip]
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <f>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   4 <f+0x4>
            4: R_386_PC32   __i686.get_pc_thunk.cx
   8:   81 c1 02 00 00 00       add    $0x2,%ecx
            a: R_386_GOTPC  _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
   e:   8b 81 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%ecx),%eax
            10: R_386_GOT32 v1
  14:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  16:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  18:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  1b:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  1e:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  1f:   c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .text.__i686.get_pc_thunk.cx:

00000000 <__i686.get_pc_thunk.cx>:
   0:   8b 0c 24                mov    (%esp),%ecx
   3:   c3                      ret
```

Machine code walk-through:

- *(Offsets 0x0 and 0x1)* The standard function prologue.
- *(Offset 0x3)* The call to `__i686.get_pc_thunk.cx` prepares for
  PC-relative addressing by loading the address of the instruction
  after the call into register `%ecx`.
- *(Offset 0x8)* The value in `%ecx` is adjusted to point to the start
  of the global offset table.  This adjustment is signalled by the
  relocation entry of type `R_386_GOTPC`.
- *(Offset 0xE)* The address of global `v1` is retrieved.  The
  `R_386_GOT32` relocation supplies the offset of `v1`'s entry from
  the base of the global offset table.
- *(Offset 0x14)* The value in `v1` is retrieved into register `%eax`.
- *(Offsets 0x16--0x1F)* The rest of the computation for function `f`.

In the final shared object, the linker patches the function's code to
the following:

```
% gcc -shared -o a.so a.o
% objdump --disassemble a.so
...snip...
0000044c <f>:
 44c:   55                      push   %ebp
 44d:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 44f:   e8 18 00 00 00          call   46c <__i686.get_pc_thunk.cx>
 454:   81 c1 a0 1b 00 00       add    $0x1ba0,%ecx
 45a:   8b 81 f8 ff ff ff       mov    -0x8(%ecx),%eax
 460:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 462:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
...snip...
```

- Assuming that the object gets loaded at offset *O* in memory, the
  call instruction at offset 0x44F will load *O*+0x454+0x1BA0, i.e.,
  *O*+0x1FF4 into `%ecx`.
- The instruction at offset 0x45A subtracts 8 from `%ecx`
  to get the address of the slot for `v1` in the global offset table,
  i.e., the slot for `v1` is at offset 0x1FEC from the start of the
  shared object.

Looking at the dynamic relocation records for the shared object, we
see a relocation record instructing the runtime loader to store the
actual address for `v1` at offset 0x1FEC.

```
% objdump -R a.so
DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE
...snip...
00001fec R_386_GLOB_DAT    v1
...snip...
```

Further reading:

- Pat Beirne's "[Study of ELF loading and relocs](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/users/p/patb/public_html/elf_relocs.html)" has more information about ELF relocations.