# unsupported symbol modifier in branch relocation: "call printf@PLT"

Tags: macos, assembly, compiler-errors, clang, mach-o

I'm following a [C compiler writing journey](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/acwj) to [generate assembly code](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/acwj/tree/master/04_Assembly) for evaluating a binary expression value.

Here's the out assembly codes (saved in file "`out.s`"):

```
    .text
LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
_printint:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    nop
    leave
    ret

    .globl  _main
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    $2, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    $5, %r10
    imulq   %r9, %r10
    addq    %r8, %r10
    movq    $8, %r8
    movq    $3, %r9
    movq    %r8,%rax
    cqo
    idivq   %r9
    movq    %rax,%r8
    subq    %r8, %r10
    movq    %r10, %rdi
    call    _printint
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

When running it with

`cc -o out out.s`

, it complained with

```
out.s:13:2: error: unsupported symbol modifier in branch relocation
 call printf@PLT
 ^
```

How is the error happened and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

PS:

1. I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.2
2. cc version is

```
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

3. The souce codes are compiled with
   `cc -o comp1 -g cg.c expr.c gen.c main.c scan.c tree.c`

Comment: Do MacOS Mach-O objects even use a PLT?  Or does it just need to be lower case?  That doesn't look like asm for MacOS; on MacOS C symbol names are prefixed with a leading `_` in asm, like `_printf`.  I think that `.s` file looks like it's for Linux.  Same x86-64 System V calling convention; different name-mangling convention.

Comment: `call _printf` works. Thanks @PeterCordes

Comment: @PeterCordes MacOS & iOS don't use PLT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260207/weak-symbol-aliases-on-os-x-similar-to-those-on-linux-or-a-closest-equivalent

Comment: @Kamil.S: the answer on that question doesn't say that.  Defaulting to non-interposable symbols doesn't imply no PLT.  I assume your statement is true (and would be the obvious explanation for why this doesn't assemble on Mach-O, instead of just failing to link), but your link doesn't directly back that up, unless I missed something in comments or a side-note in the question or answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447676/5329717, but no Apple doc reference to back this up unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

`call _printf` works. Thanks @PeterCordes.

Wondering the error prompt by cc though.