# Difference between main and __libc_start_main

Tags: c, disassembly, decompiling, ida

I am beginning to get into the reverse engineering and am using IDA Pro and am working on deassembling a binary.

I am trying to find the memory address for the `main` function of the C program I am working with.

However, I see that there is a function in IDA for:
`main` and for `__libc_start_main`

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970281/whats-going-on-in-libc-start-main) but I am afraid I still don't understand. Can someone help me understand the differences between the two, and which one is which?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__libc_start_main` is called first, and it invokes `main`.  The former is part of the platform and does some initialization that most people don't even realize is happening, such preparing the threading system.  The latter is the entry point of the user program and contains the "regular" code.

Comment: For example, would one of the things `__libc_start_main` do is link any of the `include` files, since that happens before the my `main` function in my code?

Comment: No, the loading of dynamically linked libraries happens elsewhere (but also before `main`).

Comment: Can you give an example of one of things "...that most people don't even realize is happening.", just to expand on the answer, and then I can accept =)

Comment: It probably does some other critical things like initialize your stack pointer.  And if `main` returns, `__libc_start_main` exits with the return value as the status.