# buffer over flow i'm getting these error's

Tags: buffer-overflow, strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char buffer[10];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
printf("%s\n", &buffer);
}
```

how ever i'm getting the gcc error 
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy
and when I do gdb its showing different strcpy 
0x080483a7 :   call 0x80482b8 "strcpy @ plt>"
I don't know what is plt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add header

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: here is a stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469274/what-does-plt-mean-here

Comment: hmm I don't really understand it.. whats difference between strcpy and  strcpy@plt 
Does this strcpy@plt effects practice of bufferoverflow? 
and when I input a commend of disass strcpy it says ""No symbol "strcpy" in current context""

Comment: No it does not. strcpy@plt is just an indirection given so that the library can be loaded anywhere in the virtual address space without changing addresses at every location of call to strcpy.