# What's the purpose of signal pt in this example

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb

What does `callq  400b90 <signal@plt>` do?

How would it look line in C?

```
4013a2:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
4013a6:       be a0 12 40 00          mov    $0x4012a0,%esi
4013ab:       bf 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edi
4013b0:       e8 db f7 ff ff          callq  400b90 <signal@plt>
4013b5:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
4013b9:       c3                      retq
```

Comment: `signal(2, 0x4012a0)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469274/what-does-plt-mean-here

Comment: looks like its detecting if ctrl + c is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does callq  400b90 <signal@plt> do?

Call the signal function via the PLT (procedure linkage table). So more technical: It pushes the current instruction pointer onto the stack and jumps to `signal@plt`.

> How would it look line in C?

```
void* foo(void) {
    return signal(2, (void *) 0x4012a0);
}
```

Let's look at your code line-by-line:

```
sub    $0x8,%rsp
```

This reserves some stack space. You can ignore this (the stack space is unused).

```
mov    $0x4012a0,%esi
mov    $0x2,%edi
```

Put the value `0x4012a0` and `0x2` in the registers ESI and EDI. By the ABI, this is how arguments are passed to a function.

```
callq  400b90 <signal@plt>
```

Call the function `signal` through the PLT. The PLT has something to do with the dynamic linker since we cannot be sure where the `signal` function will end up in memory whenthis is built. Basically, this just finds the final memory location and calls `signal`.

```
add    $0x8,%rsp
retq
```

Undo the `sub` from earlier and return to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.