# What implementation of getenv is used if no header is included?

Tags: c

I am working on a simple program for learning purposes and I see the following behavior:

If I attempt to read an environment variable using getenv it works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main() {
    printf("PATH is %s", getenv("PATH"));
    return 0;
}
```

If I do not include stdlib.h, I get the expected warning:

```
env.c:7:26: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getenv’; did you mean ‘getline’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

The program still compiles. Running the program with the header runs as expected, the program without the header included gets a seg fault.

If I inspect the disassembly of both programs, I see that there is a call to getenv@PLT

```
call    getenv@PLT
```

When I output the disassembly of the 2 programs (where the only difference in the c source code is the header include), the only difference I see is that when we include the header there's an instruction to set %eax to 0 before calling getenv.

```
movl    $0, %eax
```

If I step through in gdb for the program without included header, it does jump into getenv and does run a whole lot of code within the c runtime.

I am wondering what is the exact reason why not including the header here causes this kind of behavior? Why does c let this compile?

Some info:
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
I am compiling like this:
gcc -O0 -S env.c

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469274/what-does-plt-mean-here

Comment: It assumes the function returns an `int` and misinterprets the result.  Don’t do it.

Comment: Why not post the generated assembler code here?

Comment: If you're compiling for 64 bits, it is because `int` and pointers have different sizes and an undeclared `getenv`, which returns a pointer, is considered returning a `int`. But even in that case, there should be other differences in assembly code than just setting eax to zero ; there should be a difference with the parmeter pushed on stack before `printf` call.

Comment: @JoëlHecht: Yeah I suspect there are more differences than that. But why `movl $0, %eax` at all *before* the call to getenv()? `%eax` holds the return value from the function call, so setting it before is nonsensical unless maybe the function returns `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C language, if you forget to include the header file, the `getenv()` function is interpreted as `int getenv(...)`. If you include the header file, the `getenv()` function is interpreted as `char* getenv(const char*)`. Because of implementation of `printf()` the only difference in your case is the size of the return value. If `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*)`, then you have no problem (this happens for 32-bit programs). If `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)`, you get an error (this happens for 64-bit programs). This is explained in the comment #5

Comment: You won't always get an error on 64 bit, which makes this more insidious.

Comment: I agree with you